# Understanding the Falting's Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm an undergraduate student of mathematics, but soon I'll graduate, and as a personal project I want to understand Falting's Theorem, specifically I want to understand Falting's proof; but yet I have no clue where to start studying.

I already have some notions on Scheme Theory and I have studied classical algebraic geometry before. So my first guess is that I need to consolidate my knowledge on modern algebraic geometry and then move to it's applications to curves.

I made some research before asking this question and I found "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" by Qing Liu, I guess that might be a good start, he even states in the preface that the material covered in the book will allow the student to approach more specialized books like "Arithmetic Geometry" edited by Silverman and Cornell (this books contains the proof of Falting's Theorem).

I also found [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/ntslearn.html) of a Stanford seminar about the topic, which might help.

Finally I found [Milne's notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/av.html) on Abelian Varieties in which he gives the proof of Falting's theorem.

So, my question is simple, where do I start and which book or notes should I follow?

Comment: I don't know if asking this is appropriate, but, can I ask the previous question in math overflow?

Comment: Here's something Matt Emerton wrote about learning arithmetic geometry more generally: math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller/bin/emerton-roadmap.pdf

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: That is actually pretty good advice, yet I wonder, I'm lucky enough to have copies of Hartshorne's, Mumford's and Liu's books. so which one is better for what I want? I mean I am certainly reading and solving problems from them all, but I really want to focus on a single book for a while. Again my guess is Liu's book is ideal for this situation, but I don't know, I might be wrong.